# jQuery won't read JSON response (using $.post)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, forms, submit

In a nutshell, I have a form, which upon submissions, sends data to a serverside script to process a function, return data in JSON format for me to parse and spit back out onto the page.

1. jQuery sends data to "createUser.php" via the `$.post` method

   ```
   $("#create_submit").click(function(){
       $.post("/createUser.php", {
           create_user_name: $('#create_user_name').val(),
           create_user_email: $('#create_user_email').val(),
           create_user_password: $('#create_user_password').val() },
           function(data){
               alert(data.response);
           }, "json");
   });
   ```
2. "createUser.php" returns JSON data

   ```
   <?php
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   $return['response'] = 'hmm...';
   echo json_encode($return);
   exit;
   ?>
   ```

Maybe it's me, but I can't seem to get the alert that I need. What's going on!?

Comment: Posting an example of the JSON output would be very helpful. Also, is the alert being called at all? Or just not outputting what you're expecting?

Comment: this is my createUser.php 

<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$return['response'] = 'hmm...';
echo json_encode($return);
exit;
?>

Comment: Alert is not being called at all...but when i take out the "json" parameter of the $.post method, the alert shows up

Comment: Have you checked createUser.php to see if it's outputting JSON? If you don't have PHP 5.2 it will give you an error. Also, if you have error reporting to show E_NOTICE's then you'll get a E_NOTICE for not having $return defined.

Comment: if i direct my browser directly to createUser.php i see the JSON string 

{"usernameErr":"That username already exists!","emailErr":"That email already exists","response":"hmm..."}

Comment: Remove "json" and just do an alert on data. See if the response is JSON formatted. There is a chance something is being outputted that shouldn't on the POST request (you didn't post the full PHP file)

Comment: William, I did as you said and took out the "json" parameter and just did an alert on the "data" object. An alert box showed up BUT it was empty. My javascript log (in firebug) isn't coming up with anything

Answer (score 3):

I think the `data` argument to your callback function already is the data, and has no `response` member.

Try `function(data){ alert(data); }`

Documentation: [**jquery.post**](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

Comment: pekka, like i noted above, the alert doesn't even pop up when i have the "json" parameter in the $.post method...however when i take that optional parameter out, the alert seems to work (though it doesnt alert the data, just says 'undefined'

Comment: Make sure you're checking your JavaScript error log. It might be giving you a JavaScript error when alerting data.response because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you look at the json post example in the docs (bottom)?  If you specify data type you do not access the response.  Since you know that's wrong, take it out of your example, try again, and update your question if you're still having an issue.  If it's not that, it seems like the most likely culprit is invalid json.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your answers, JSON is only being outputted when you do the above POST request. If you do a normal GET request it works fine. To test this, change $.post to $.get (and clear the variables create_user_* if need be) and see if you get a response then.

If you do, then you need to check your createUser.php file and see why the POST request returns no JSON, but the GET request does. It looks like this is a PHP issue, not a JavaScript/JSON/jQuery issue.